# A Python equivalent of a Groovy spread-dot operator

Tags: python, groovy

I loved how groovy works with collections and dictionaries, the code is so readable and has a ton of syntactic sugar.
Working with Python I miss some of the operators from Groovy
Specifically, the "spread-dot" operator. What it does is it creates a new collection that consists from only the specified property of all the children, for example

```
A = [
   { "a": "1", "b": "2"},
   { "a": "3", "b": "4"},
   { "a": "5", "b": "6"}
]
B = A*.b
```

And B would be ["2", "4", "6"]

The direct equivalent for Python would be
`[a.b for a in A]` 
but it's awkward to use

Is there a better, more readable way of doing it?
In the exact example above it's not so bad because it's just one level, but consider this

```
response.json().data.ConfigRecords.page.records*.ASV
```

vs

```
[a['ASV'] for a in response.json()['data']['ConfigRecords']['page']['records']]
```

Comment: "The direct equivalent for Python would be `[a.b for a in A]` ... Is there a better, more readable way of doing it?" no, not really. This is about the shortest and most concise way to do it... also it should likely be `[a["b"] for a in A]` unless you're using a special dict-like type that allows basically translating `__getattr__` to `__getitem__`. you can't get an item from a regular dict by calling the attribute of the same name.

Comment: IMAO this is a case of wanting to put too much into a single line of code.. split it up into: `records = response.json()['data']['ConfigRecords']['page']['records']` and `[record["ASV"] for record in records]`

Comment: "Is there a better, more readable way of doing it?" - The "better" part is subjective.  Would you like to optimize for performance, readability, smallest code, or something else?

Comment: if you use `pandas.DataFrame` then you can get `A.b` or `A['b']`

Answer (score 0):

With standard list/dictionary you need `[row["b"] for row in A]`
and for me is it not akward but very readable code.

```
A = [
   { "a": "1", "b": "2"},
   { "a": "3", "b": "4"},
   { "a": "5", "b": "6"}
]

print([row['b'] for row in A])
```

Result:

```
['2', '4', '6']
```

---

But if you use `pandas.DataFrame` then you can use `A.b` or `A["b"]`.
Eventually it may need `.tolist()` to get it as `list` instead of `pandas.Series`.

```
A = [
   { "a": "1", "b": "2"},
   { "a": "3", "b": "4"},
   { "a": "5", "b": "6"}
]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(A)

print(df['b'])   # pandas.Series
print(df.b)      # pandas.Series

print(df['b'].tolist())  # list
print(df.b.tolist())     # list
```

Result:

```
0    2
1    4
2    6
Name: b, dtype: object

0    2
1    4
2    6
Name: b, dtype: object

['2', '4', '6']

['2', '4', '6']
```

It can also select only some rows - ie rows which have `a > 2`

```
A[ A.a > 2 ]['b']
```

---

For me more readable is to split code into three lines.

```
data = response.json()
records = data['data']['ConfigRecords']['page']['records']
asv = [item['ASV'] for item in records]
```